# Is there any impact of having a script running x seconds in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a script that runs every 1 second looking for a change in a value. Consider the code bellow:

```
setInterval(function() {
   var inputOne = jQuery('#0_img_file');
   var inputTwo = jQuery('.0_img-file').attr('src');
   return function() {
      if (inputOne.val() !== inputTwo) {
         jQuery('.0_img-file').attr('src', inputOne.val());
      }
   }
}(), 1000);
```

So heres my question, could this script affect the site experience to the user or any kind of other stuff am not aware of?

I know there is functions in jquery like `onChange, change` etc but it only works if the user changes the value automatically, I've noticed it does not capture changes if other scripts change the value of an input.

Comment: um, The jQuery object stored in input1 will never equal the src attribute of input2....

Comment: What other scripts do you have on the page, that do change the input field value? Don’t those offer any events/hooks to call custom code when such a change happens?

Comment: `inputOne` is jQuery object. `inputTwo` is a string. And you compare them `if (inputOne !== inputTwo)` How can a jQuery object and a string ever equal each other. It is like seeing if a pizza is the same thing as an apple.

Comment: @epascarello thanks for noticing, I did this on the go, its not the actual script.

Comment: And your current change will fail since you only read the value once. That will not ever update.

Comment: @CBroe there is so many other scripts running. Its Magento platform so there is so many stuff in the background.

Comment: @epascarello happy now?

Comment: What type of HTML elements are `#0_img_file` and `.0_img-file`? Your variable names suggest they are both input fields – file inputs? (But then how would it have a `src` attribute?)

Comment: @CBroe The id element is a readonly input field, while the class is a img file.  So when the input value changes the src attribute would change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code runs 10 times per second, not once. However, your browser is likely running on a computer with at least 2 multigigahertz cores with hyperthreading, megabytes of caching on board and you name it. So no, repeating a trivial task every 100ms (or 1s) is not going to noticeably slow down your browser, JS is usually rather fast.

Just don't run 100 jobs like this, you *will* start to feel it. And of course, you should just hook onto events of the scripts modifying the values, instead of polling for changes, which should be possible just fine with Javascript - due to its prototyped nature it's trivial to plug into existing code.

Answer (score 0):

> I've noticed it does not capture changes if other scripts change the value of an input.

That's because you probably use `.attr('value', something)` or `.attr('checked', true')` instead of `.val(something)` and `.prop('checked', true)`.

> So heres my question, could this script affect the site experience to the user or any kind of other stuff am not aware of?

Of course it can. Especially if the script make some heavy operations. Many browsers execute Javascript in only one thread. So when your script start, the browser will freeze during it's execution. If you have only one light script, it's ok. But if you abuse of this method, you will have some performances problems.

Comment: Trust me when I say it doesn't not capture the change by another script.

Comment: Magus, it’s not about reading the value, but been notified when it _changes_.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the site will be little slower. The script calls a function every 1 second, so it will not have much problem on good computers. Besides, not everyone has good computers. Some users uses slow computers will have problem in perfomance, so usinh other way is needed.